# Add a service_account.json to kubectl secrets

Tags: kubernetes

How to add a service_account.json file to kubernetes secrets? I tried

`kubectl create secret generic service_account.json -n sample --from-file=service_account=service_account.json`

but it returns an error failed to create secret Secret "service_account.json" is invalid: metadata.name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `service_account.json` as the (metadata) name for a Kubernetes resource. Here's the documentation on permitted [Object Names and IDs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/)

You can use:

```sh
kubectl create secret generic foo \
--namespace=sample \
--from-file=key.json=service_account.json
```

> **NOTE** The secret is called `foo` and it creates a key called `key.json` whose value is the content of the file called `service_account.json`.

> **NOTE** If you don't wish to rename the object name in the secret, you can omit it; I renamed the file `service_account.json` to `key.json` in the secret. To retain the original name, just use `--from-file=service_account.json`.

You should then able to volume mount the secret in the Container where you need to use it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    control-plane: controller-manager
  name: system
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: {}
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-container
          volumeMounts:
            - name: bar
              mountPath: /secrets
      volumes:
        - name: bar
          secret:
            secretName: foo
```

> **NOTE** The container can access the `foo` secret's content as `/secrets/key.json`.

Intentionally distinct names `foo`, `bar` etc. for clarity